# Enable WebApplicationInitializer implementation with jetty

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, jetty

This problem relates to configuring a Jetty 9 server with a war developed in Maven/Spring 3.0.
A log file exists in 'src/main/resources/log4j.properties' in the project and I can see the logs printed when I run 'mvn jetty:run'. However, the logs do not get printed when I deploy a compiled war file in Jetty 9. I simply do not see any log at all (no errors either).

I compiled the war file using the following command:
'mvn compile war:war'

I opened the war file and saw that the log4j.properties was located in WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties.

Here is some additional details about the versions being used:

1. Jetty 9.0.7
2. Spring 3.2.4
3. Log4J: 1.5.5

Does any one know what I am doing wrong? Please help!

Edit:
We start to think it maybe the web application is not loaded at all. We are using org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer instead of web.xml and here is our war structure.

```
├── META-INF
└── WEB-INF
    ├── classes
    │   ├── applicationContext.xml
    │   ├── com
    │   │   └──….{classes}
    │   └── log4j.properties
    └── lib
        ├── …{jars}
```

Comment: Is the `log4j.properties` in the war file? If yes, in which folder?

Comment: Hi Ralph, the log4j.properties located in WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties in the war file.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!
The issue is never about log4j. It is because WebApplicationInitializer need servlet 3.1 support which is not enabled as default.
We have enabled following in the start.ini

```
# ===========================================================
# Enable additional webapp environment configurators 
# -----------------------------------------------------------
 OPTIONS=plus
 etc/jetty-plus.xml

# ===========================================================
# Enable servlet 3.1 annotations
# -----------------------------------------------------------
 OPTIONS=annotations
 etc/jetty-annotations.xml
```

Comment: What if I run my server programmatically and I do not have any `start.ini` file. Would you have a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

When your pom has `<packaging>war</packaging>` of try `mvn package` to get the war instead